# Dont display multiple rows more than once in count query?

Tags: php, count

I'm creating a website that COUNTS all the occurences of something.
Table:
Pizza     John
Google    John
Pizza     Harry

Lets say you like google and pizza. It will show it like this:
John, John, Harry.

I would like it to appear like this:
John, Harry.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code. Does it have anything to do with the while loop inside the while loop? How could I make it appear the way I want it to.. I can't figure it out.

```
$people_like = mysqli_query ($link,    
    "SELECT user_liked_by FROM ( 
        SELECT COUNT(user_liked_by) AS total, id, user_liked_by
        FROM whatilike WHERE whats_liked LIKE '%$thing_liked%' &&
            user_liked_by !='$user'
        GROUP BY user_liked_by
        ORDER BY COUNT(user_liked_by) DESC ) as names;
    ");

while ($rpl = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($people_like)) {
    $person_like_u = $rpl ['user_liked_by'];
    $pluq = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE 
                                    username='$person_like_u'");

    while ($pluqr = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($pluq)) {
        $pli = $pluqr ['profile_pic'];
        echo "<a href='profile.php?u=$person_like_u'  >
            <img src='data/user_photos/$pli' height='50px' width='50px'
                    style='border-radius:400px;' id='ioplu' ></a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT user_liked_by
        FROM whatilike WHERE whats_liked LIKE '%$thing_liked%' &&
        user_liked_by !='$user'
         GROUP BY user_liked_by
        ORDER BY COUNT(user_liked_by) DESC `

Comment: Possibly looking for `DISTINCT` command?

Comment: @user3208921 `DISTINCT` will remove duplicates from the result. So if John shows up twice in the rest of the query, it'll only appear once in the result. Example here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: DISTINCT does not fix it... don't know why the group by function should do the trick... thanks, though

Comment: fixed it. just removed a while loop :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$people = [];    
while ($rpl = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($people_like)) {
  $people[] = $rpl ['user_liked_by'];
}

$people = array_unique(array_map("trim",$people));
foreach($people as $p){
  $pluq = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE 
                                username='$p'");

  while ($pluqr = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($pluq)) {
    $pli = $pluqr ['profile_pic'];
    echo "<a href='profile.php?u=$person_like_u'  >
        <img src='data/user_photos/$pli' height='50px' width='50px'
                style='border-radius:400px;' id='ioplu' ></a>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO Much but i fixed it by removing the first while loop :D